# If $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of the same dimension such that $V$ meets $W^\perp$, then $W$ meets $V^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthonormal

I'm having a little difficulty understanding the proof for orthogonal complements.  I kind of understand orthogonal complements, but I cannot seem to find a logic to this.  I'm trying to follow along with theorems and definitions, but I'm not far.  Any advice on how to go about his proof problem?

> Let V and W be two subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the same dimension, $m$.  Assume $\exists \mathbf{v} \in V \setminus \left \{ 0 \right \}$ such that $\mathbf{v} \in W^{\bot}$.
>
> (a) Prove that $\exists \mathbf{w} \in W \setminus \left \{ 0 \right \}$ such that $\mathbf{w} \in V^{\bot}$.
>
> (b) Show by an example that the conclusion of part (a) may not hold if V and W do not have the same dimension.

Comment: Help yourself out with an example.  Let n >2 and let V be the space generated by (1,0), W be the space generated by (0,1).  Can you prove a for this case?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to.

Comment: What is the orthogonal projection of the vector (1,1) onto V.

Answer (score 1):

We are given two subspaces $V$ and $W$ of $\Bbb R^n$ such that $V\cap W^\perp\neq\{\vec 0\}$ and $\dim V=\dim W$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
\dim\left(W\cap V^\perp\right)
&= \dim\left(\left(W\cap V^\perp\right)^{\perp\perp}\right) \\
&= \dim\left(\left(W^\perp+V\right)^\perp\right) \\
&= n-\dim\left(W^\perp+V\right) \\
&= n-\left(\dim\left(W^\perp \right)+\dim(V)-\dim\left(W^\perp\cap V\right)\right) \\
&= n-\left(\dim\left(V^\perp \right)+\dim(V)-\dim\left(W^\perp\cap V\right)\right) \\
&= n-\left(n-\dim\left(W^\perp\cap V\right)\right) \\
&= \dim\left(W^\perp\cap V\right) \\
&>0
\end{align*}
Do you see why each equality holds?

Answer (score 0):

Think about projection onto $V$. This defines a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow V$ whose kernel is precisely $V^\perp$. What are the dimensions of this projection's matrix, restricted to $W$? What does the given condition say about this matrix, if an appropriate basis for $V$ is chosen?